# Passing data between ViewModels in MVVM WPF application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, unity-container

From one of my ViewModel I have below call which fetches information from server.

```
 List<Customer> listOfCustomers = GetCustomerList(domain,password);
```

What is the best way to  pass this information id listOfcustomers to another ViewModel (CustomerViewModel) in MVVM scenario.

Do I need to use Unity here , or publish using event aggregator as RichardOD said below.

Comment: Looks like model, not view model !

Answer (score 5):

Your login ViewModel shouldn't be getting this information. The login ViewModel is for logging in, not for pulling data. Your CustomerViewModel should be pulling that data *after* the user is successfully validated—likely based on the validated user name.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a vague question, but often if you wish to communicate between ViewModels in a loosely coupled manner, then you should consider using an [Event Aggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html).